# cython id() function causes integer overflow

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I have a larger project which uses some cython generated libraries. At some point I use the `id()` function to get the address of an object. The address is then used as a key in a dictionary.

Here the code of the .pyx file that causes the trouble

```py
    @cython.cdivision(True)
    def get_position(self, Xp_py):
        cdef int ix = id(Xp_py)
        cdef int i = self.search_position(Xp_py, ix)
```

The `id()` function causes the following error:
"OverflowError: value too large to convert to int", which is strange since the type of `id()` is `int`...

I tried to change the type of `ix` to `long` and it don't crash, but the results of the following function are weird. I hope someone can give some insight on this behaviour.

Comment: 1) You should probably use `uintptr_t` - it's designed to store a pointer, and as an implementation detail `id` returns a pointer address. 2) Any further guess at "results are weird" will require a proper [mcve] 3) Your function (as shown) doesn't do any division, so the `cdivision` decorator is a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks, `uintptr_t` did it. The weird results came from the conversion to `long`, now its working as it should. The division is used below in the function, but that part of the code was not necessary for the question, as is the decorator line, sorry for that.